# How to show / update the merge status?

Tags: git

I am in the middle of a merge (master into dev).

There are lots of merge conflicts and after fixing some I would like to see a list of those files which still have a conflict. What's the easiest flow for that?

Comment: `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that git doesn't know when you fix the conflicts if don't tell it, to do that you need to run `git add <fixed_file>`.

Then you can use `git status` and see which files have the `U` (U for updated) status.

Alternatively you can use the following command to filter by the status:

`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`